# How can I check to see if two cylinders overlap?

Tags: graphics3d, regions, mesh

Is there a simple way for me to determine if a cylinder `a` and cylinder `b` overlap in the 3D space? I have spent a few hours looking into this, but haven't yet found a solution.

For a little while, I thought that `MemberRegion[]` might be useful, but it does not seem to be working in 3 dimensions.

[image: For example, here two cylinders are overlapping]

For example, here, above, two cylinders are overlapping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Region@RegionIntersection[ 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, 2],   
   Cylinder[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}, 4]]
```

[image]

or

```
RegionDimension@
 RegionIntersection[ 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, 2],  
   Cylinder[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}, 4]]
```

(*  3  *)

Comment: Thanks! I had thought, for some reason, that RegionIntersection[] didn't account for the {x,y,z} position!

Comment: How could it *not*???